# Error while injecting Firebase into a provider

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to inject Firebase into a provider, so I can set the baseURL in the app config. I have included all the necessary files and I am injecting the Firebase provider and I have defined the Firebase dependency. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The error message I get is:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module firebaseManager due to:
>
> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $firebase

The code for the provider:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('firebaseManager',['firebase'])
.provider("firebaseManager", function($firebase){
    var baseURL = "https://xxx.firebaseio.com";
    var rootRef = new Firebase(baseURL);

    this.$get = function(){
        return{
            getInventory: function(){
                var ref = rootRef.child("inventory");
                var sync = $firebase(ref);
                return sync.$asArray();

            }
        }
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you aren't doing anything here that requires the complexity of calling a provider. You may have a perfectly valid reason you haven't shared, but I'll go ahead and suggest that you utilize a factory instead:

```
angular.module('firebaseManager',['firebase'])
.factory("getInventory", function($firebase){
    var baseURL = "https://xxx.firebaseio.com";
    var rootRef = new Firebase(baseURL);
    var sync = $firebase(rootRef.child('inventory'));

    // this returns the same synchronized array each time, 
    // which is generally preferable
    return sync.$asArray();

    // to return a copy each time (probably a bad idea),
    // do something like this instead
    //return function() {
    //   return sync.$asArray();
    //}
});
```

To specifically answer your question, the dependencies get injected into the $get method, not the provider() function.

```
angular.module('firebaseManager',['firebase'])
.provider("firebaseManager", function(){
    var baseURL = "https://xxx.firebaseio.com";
    var rootRef = new Firebase(baseURL);

    this.$get = ['$firebase', function($firebase){
        return{
            getInventory: function(){
                var ref = rootRef.child("inventory");
                var sync = $firebase(ref);
                return sync.$asArray();

            }
        }
    }];
});
```

Also, you should utilize $window instead of the global Firebase variable as this works better with jslint/jshint and with mocks when you employ unit testing.

```
//$window can be injected as a dependency
var rootRef = new $window.Firebase(baseURL);
```